# WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 integration with other Billing Engines

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to integrate an unknown billing engine with `WSO2`. But there's no documentation on the `WSO2 docs` for integrating any other billing engine (other than `Stripe`) with `WSO2 API Manager`.

If someone has developed an extension for any billing engine other than `Stripe`, or if there's any article or tutorial explaining how to do it, I'd appreciate if you'd shared it with me.

Even an explanation of [wso2-am-stripe-plugin](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/wso2-am-stripe-plugin) would be helpful, since there's no documentation available for the plugin.

Comment: What is the billing engine you are trying to integrate with APIM-3.2.0?

Comment: It's a local billing engine [zarinpal](https://www.zarinpal.com/). My problem is not with the billing engine! It's the lack of documentation on [wso2-am-stripe-plugin](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/wso2-am-stripe-plugin). If there's a similar plugin for Paypal or any other engine, I would be able to compare it with stripe-plugin and figure out what every piece of code does.